# Basic Autthentication in Selenium without choosing an element

Tags: selenium, basic-authentication

I need to log in to a popup window and I tested every method proposed by people and none of them worked! So what I am trying to do is to simply go to a url and promptly type the `username\t` and `password` and hit the `Enter`. Normally this can be done by choosing that `input` element, but not in this case. How can I type without choosing the element?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried focusing on the new frame that is generated by the popup?

Comment: @JonathanKempf `IAlert alert = driver.SwitchTo().Alert();` ? even if I switch to the new frame don't I need to choose an element?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, this isn't an alert from the JavaScript embedded in or referenced from the loaded HTML. This is the BASIC AUTH dialog. Doing BASIC AUTH in selenium seems to be an [open issue](https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/34), although there's reportedly a [workaround](https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/34#issuecomment-191403370).

Comment: @das-g thanks. yep I tried that `"driver.get(http://username:password@www.url.com/);"` one but doesn't work for me either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I've tried and has worked for me in the past.

```
System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait("UserNoome");
System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait({TAB});
System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait("Passwoord");
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks Kam.

Comment: Alright for pressing`Log In` button you need to press Tab one more time after filling the Password. so the last step should be something like `System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait("\t\n");`

Comment: @HoomanYar The last step should be `System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait({ENTER});`

Comment: Please also note that if you declare the following namespace `using System.Windows.Forms;`, you will only have to write the code as `SendKeys.SendWait("Blah");`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the focus is on the frame. Try using `Actions` for the needful [code in java] :

```java
Actions action = new Actions(webdriver); //replace with your driver
action.sendKeys("username").perform();
action.sendKeys("\t").perform(); //possibly Keys.TAB
action.sendKeys("password").perform();
action.sendKeys("\n").perform(); //possibly Keys.ENTER
```

***Edit*** : Also `keyDown(Keys.TAB)` could be used as an alternate to `sendKeys("\t")`

Comment: doesn't work. gives me an `OpenQA.Selenium.UnhandledAlertException` in the first `sendKeys`